# Script to update confluence page through jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, confluence

I wanted a script that would take the values from a directory and output them to a specific confluence page and update it when there are check-ins.
I'm assuming this can be done through jenkins via https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin
Can you please help me with the script.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This site is intended to help you with scripts that you might have already created and problems with those scripts.  You'll need to put in a little more effort and show us the script that you tried to develop.

Comment: That plugin appears to add attachments only. Updating a page is easy with the REST API. https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/ Write a script to do what you need and come back here with issues.